What is the formula for copying a specific cell from one Google Sheet tab to another automatically?
Here is my goal:

In Tab 1, there is a list of completed tasks, sorted by date
completed. Some are highlighted in red.

In Tab 2 in the same Sheet, all tasks from Tab 1 that have been
highlighted red have been copied over.


How do I formulate this in Google Sheets?

Copy highlighted cells from one sheet to another
Please be informed that using Google Sheet formula is not possible for copying highlighted cells. alternatively, you can use Google Apps script which can handle more complex actions and automate processes beyond what formulas can do.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Copy the highlighted cells', 'copyCells')
    .addToUi();
}

function copyCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tab 1'); 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tab 2'); 

  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var redColor = '#ff0000'; 
  var targetRow = 1; 

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (backgrounds[i].includes(redColor)) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1, 1, values[i].length).setValues([values[i]]);
      targetRow++;
    }
  }
}

And, here is the sample sheet:

And Output:

These are the steps you can do to import and run the script provided above.
In Google Sheet.

Go to Extension > App script
Delete the pre-made code and paste the code above.
Make sure to run the "OnOpen" function.
Provide authrozation and run again.
Go back to Google Sheets and Click on "Custom Menu".


Reference:
Custom Menu
